# Declarar variable escalar

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente código sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUsuario
@uNombre NVARCHAR(50), 
@uPass NVARCHAR(50), 
@responseMessage NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY

    INSERT INTO usuario (id, nombre, pass, fecha_alta)
    VALUES(newid(),@uNombre, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @uPass),getdate())

    SET @responseMessage='Usuario agregado.'

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
END CATCH

END
```

que obviamente es para dar de alta un usuario, el problema es al ejecutar el proceso almacenado lo hago con el siguiente codigo:

```
DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)
EXEC AddUsuario
      @uNombre = N'Admin',
      @uPass = N'123',
      @responseMessage=@responseMessage OUTPUT
```

Marca que debo declarar la variable **@responseMessage**

```
Mens. 137, Nivel 15, Estado 2, Línea 4
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@responseMessage".
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
    DECLARE @return_value int,
            @responseMessage nvarchar(250)

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[AddUsuario]
            @uNombre = N'Admin',
            @uPass = N'123',
            @responseMessage = @responseMessage OUTPUT

    SELECT  @responseMessage as N'@responseMessage'

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

Comment: el campo es **uniqueidentifier** no puedo poner **"1"** por eso es **newid()**

Comment: Edite la respuesta, me avisas si funciona @davidarellano

Comment: Gracias por responder, El propósito de **@responseMessage** es almacenar el mensaje de éxito o error del proceso almacenado, tu solo le agregaste otra variable que no esta en el proceso.

Comment: Repliqué tu caso en mi management, ese fue el resultado de ejecutar tu sp y entiendo el fin de tu message, en mi caso si funcionó, pero eso te pregunté si funcionó.